# Can't connect to Wifi after coming back from standby mode (15.04)

Tags: wireless, 15.04

I just installed Ubuntu 15.04 on a brand new laptop. The wifi is working
correctly, until I close the lid. When I reopen it, I am no longer able to
connect, and no amount of fiddling with the network-manager applet will make my
connection come back.

[image: Disabled through hardware switch]

My system is in french, but here it says that the Wi-Fi is currently disabled by
a hardware switch. I have no hardware switch on this computer. I do have
a `Fn+F11` keybinding that should toggle Airplane mode, but it does nothing.

I ran a few diagnosis tools before and after closing the lid,
here are the outputs:

### `ifconfig wlan0`

#### Before

```
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 48:51:b7:bb:67:00  
          inet adr:192.168.1.14  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Masque:255.255.255.0
          adr inet6: fe80::4a51:b7ff:febb:6700/64 Scope:Lien
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          Packets reçus:149 erreurs:0 :0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:177 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 lg file transmission:1000 
          Octets reçus:62235 (62.2 KB) Octets transmis:32517 (32.5 KB)
```

#### After

```
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 48:51:b7:bb:67:00  
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          Packets reçus:258 erreurs:0 :0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:288 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 lg file transmission:1000 
          Octets reçus:81657 (81.6 KB) Octets transmis:88674 (88.6 KB)
```

I tried `sudo ifconfig wlan0 up`, but got `SIOCSIFFLAGS` timeout error
message in response.

### `iwconfig wlan0`

#### Before

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"Livebox-F1EF"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: 9C:D2:4B:57:F1:EF   
          Bit Rate=1 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=68/70  Signal level=-42 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:54   Missed beacon:0
```

#### After

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
```

I tried `sudo iwconfig wlan0 power on`, but it seems to simply switch the `Power
Management` to `on` in the previous output, but does not fix the issue.

### `rfkill-list`

#### Before

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

#### After

```
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

This is actually the weirdest part in my opinion. The whole Bluetooth part
disappeared (I do not use Bluetooth at all, so I don't really care). But it
explictly say that the wifi is not Hard blocked. So where did
`network-manager` got its information from?

### `sudo lshw -C network`

#### Before

```
*-network
     description: Interface réseau sans fil
     produit: Wireless 7260
     fabriquant: Intel Corporation
     identifiant matériel: 0
     information bus: pci@0000:02:00.0
     nom logique: wlan0
     version: c3
     numéro de série: 48:51:b7:bb:67:00
     bits: 64 bits
     horloge: 33MHz
     fonctionnalités: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
     configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.19.0-15-generic firmware=25.17.12.0 ip=192.168.1.14 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
     ressources: irq:53 mémoire:f7100000-f7101fff
```

#### After

```
*-network DÉSACTIVÉ
     description: Interface réseau sans fil
     produit: Wireless 7260
     fabriquant: Intel Corporation
     identifiant matériel: 0
     information bus: pci@0000:02:00.0
     nom logique: wlan0
     version: c3
     numéro de série: 48:51:b7:bb:67:00
     bits: 64 bits
     horloge: 33MHz
     fonctionnalités: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
     configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.19.0-15-generic firmware=25.17.12.0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
     ressources: irq:53 mémoire:f7100000-f7101fff
```

Here I can clearly see that my wifi card is disabled (big *DÉSACTIVÉ* at the
top, `link=no` in the configuration). But I have no clue as to how to enable it again.

I even tried `sudo service network-manager stop && sudo service
network-manager start`. This replaced the message from *disabled through
hardware switch* to *device not ready*.

[image]

What happen when I close the lid, and how can I re-enable the wifi when I open
it back?

### `dmesg`

```
[ 6423.908306] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[ 6423.938932] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[ 6424.556489] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Hardware error detected.  Restarting.
[ 6424.556496] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: CSR values:
[ 6424.556498] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: (2nd byte of CSR_INT_COALESCING is CSR_INT_PERIODIC_REG)
[ 6424.556503] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:        CSR_HW_IF_CONFIG_REG: 0X40c89204
[ 6424.556508] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:          CSR_INT_COALESCING: 0X80000040
[ 6424.556514] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:                     CSR_INT: 0X20000000
[ 6424.556519] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:                CSR_INT_MASK: 0X00000000
[ 6424.556523] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:           CSR_FH_INT_STATUS: 0X00000000
[ 6424.556528] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:                 CSR_GPIO_IN: 0X00000000
[ 6424.556533] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:                   CSR_RESET: 0X00000003
[ 6424.556537] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:                CSR_GP_CNTRL: 0X080003dc
[ 6424.556542] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:                  CSR_HW_REV: 0X00000144
[ 6424.556547] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:              CSR_EEPROM_REG: 0X00000000
[ 6424.556551] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:               CSR_EEPROM_GP: 0X80000000
[ 6424.556556] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:              CSR_OTP_GP_REG: 0X803a0000
[ 6424.556561] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:                 CSR_GIO_REG: 0X00080044
[ 6424.556565] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:            CSR_GP_UCODE_REG: 0X00000000
[ 6424.556570] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:           CSR_GP_DRIVER_REG: 0X00000000
[ 6424.556575] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:           CSR_UCODE_DRV_GP1: 0X00000000
[ 6424.556579] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:           CSR_UCODE_DRV_GP2: 0X00000000
[ 6424.556584] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:                 CSR_LED_REG: 0X00000018
[ 6424.556589] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:        CSR_DRAM_INT_TBL_REG: 0X00000000
[ 6424.556593] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:        CSR_GIO_CHICKEN_BITS: 0X27800200
[ 6424.556598] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:             CSR_ANA_PLL_CFG: 0Xd55555d5
[ 6424.556603] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:      CSR_MONITOR_STATUS_REG: 0X1c01019c
[ 6424.556607] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:           CSR_HW_REV_WA_REG: 0X0001001a
[ 6424.556612] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:        CSR_DBG_HPET_MEM_REG: 0Xffff0510
[ 6424.556615] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: FH register values:
[ 6424.593272] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:         FH_RSCSR_CHNL0_STTS_WPTR_REG: 0X5a5a5a5a
[ 6424.630285] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:        FH_RSCSR_CHNL0_RBDCB_BASE_REG: 0X5a5a5a5a
[ 6424.666984] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:                  FH_RSCSR_CHNL0_WPTR: 0X5a5a5a5a
[ 6424.703700] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:         FH_MEM_RCSR_CHNL0_CONFIG_REG: 0X5a5a5a5a
[ 6424.740442] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:          FH_MEM_RSSR_SHARED_CTRL_REG: 0X5a5a5a5a
[ 6424.777109] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:            FH_MEM_RSSR_RX_STATUS_REG: 0X5a5a5a5a
[ 6424.795448] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:    FH_MEM_RSSR_RX_ENABLE_ERR_IRQ2DRV: 0X5a5a5a5a
[ 6424.813787] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:                FH_TSSR_TX_STATUS_REG: 0X5a5a5a5a
[ 6424.832126] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:                 FH_TSSR_TX_ERROR_REG: 0X5a5a5a5a
[ 6424.850466] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[ 6424.850469] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Status: 0x00000000, count: -1
[ 6424.850472] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 25.17.12.0
[ 6424.850475] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xC062D497 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT          
[ 6424.850477] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xFFFFFFFF | uPc
[ 6424.850478] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x5A5A5A5A | branchlink1
[ 6424.850480] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | branchlink2
[ 6424.850481] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x197B7CC8 | interruptlink1
[ 6424.850485] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xFFFF8801 | interruptlink2
[ 6424.850490] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xC0611789 | data1
[ 6424.850494] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xFFFFFFFF | data2
[ 6424.850496] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x18C18000 | data3
[ 6424.850497] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xFFFF8801 | beacon time
[ 6424.850498] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xC062D4C9 | tsf low
[ 6424.850500] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xFFFFFFFF | tsf hi
[ 6424.850501] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x197B7C70 | time gp1
[ 6424.850503] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xFFFF8801 | time gp2
[ 6424.850504] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000020 | time gp3
[ 6424.850505] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xFFFF8801 | uCode version
[ 6424.850507] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x197B7CD8 | hw version
[ 6424.850508] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xFFFF8801 | board version
[ 6424.850510] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xFFFF8800 | hcmd
[ 6424.850511] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000296 | isr0
[ 6424.850512] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr1
[ 6424.850514] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x197B7CD0 | isr2
[ 6424.850516] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xFFFF8801 | isr3
[ 6424.850523] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xC0626424 | isr4
[ 6424.850530] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xFFFFFFFF | isr_pref
[ 6424.850537] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xC062D497 | wait_event
[ 6424.850543] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xFFFFFFFF | l2p_control
[ 6424.850544] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x5A5A5A5A | l2p_duration
[ 6424.850546] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_mhvalid
[ 6424.850547] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xC0626424 | l2p_addr_match
[ 6424.850548] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xFFFFFFFF | lmpm_pmg_sel
[ 6424.850550] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x18C18000 | timestamp
[ 6424.850551] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xFFFF8801 | flow_handler
[ 6424.850554] ieee80211 phy0: Hardware restart was requested
[ 6429.847292] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Failed to load firmware chunk!
[ 6429.847296] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Could not load the [0] uCode section
[ 6429.847302] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Failed to start RT ucode: -110
[ 6429.877948] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[ 6429.877964] WARNING: CPU: 3 PID: 831 at /build/buildd/linux-3.19.0/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/pcie/trans.c:355 iwl_pcie_apm_stop+0x6b9/0x790 [iwlwifi]()
[ 6429.877966] Modules linked in: ctr ccm binfmt_misc rfcomm bnep arc4 intel_rapl iosf_mbi x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp iwlmvm kvm_intel mac80211 uvcvideo kvm videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_core v4l2_common hid_logitech_hidpp videodev joydev rtsx_pci_ms serio_raw media snd_hda_codec_hdmi iwlwifi snd_hda_codec_realtek lpc_ich memstick snd_hda_codec_generic cfg80211 btusb bluetooth snd_soc_rt5640 mei_me snd_hda_intel snd_soc_rl6231 snd_hda_controller shpchp snd_hda_codec mei snd_soc_core snd_hwdep snd_compress snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_pcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi snd_seq snd_seq_device snd_timer snd dw_dmac i2c_hid dw_dmac_core snd_soc_sst_acpi soundcore i2c_designware_platform 8250_dw i2c_designware_core spi_pxa2xx_platform acpi_pad mac_hid parport_pc ppdev
[ 6429.878000]  lp parport autofs4 dm_crypt hid_logitech_dj usbhid hid rtsx_pci_sdmmc crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel i915 aesni_intel aes_x86_64 lrw gf128mul glue_helper ablk_helper cryptd i2c_algo_bit r8169 drm_kms_helper psmouse mii rtsx_pci drm ahci libahci wmi sdhci_acpi sdhci video
[ 6429.878018] CPU: 3 PID: 831 Comm: NetworkManager Tainted: G        W      3.19.0-15-generic #15-Ubuntu
[ 6429.878019] Hardware name: Notebook                         W54_55_94_95_97AU,AUQ/W54_55_94_95_97AU,AUQ, BIOS 5.6.5 02/10/2015
[ 6429.878021]  ffffffffc062fea8 ffff8800d3577438 ffffffff817c2205 0000000000000007
[ 6429.878023]  0000000000000000 ffff8800d3577478 ffffffff8107595a 00000001000061a8
[ 6429.878025]  ffff880118c18000 ffff880118c18000 ffff880119243098 00000000080007d4
[ 6429.878028] Call Trace:
[ 6429.878034]  [<ffffffff817c2205>] dump_stack+0x45/0x57
[ 6429.878037]  [<ffffffff8107595a>] warn_slowpath_common+0x8a/0xc0
[ 6429.878039]  [<ffffffff81075a4a>] warn_slowpath_null+0x1a/0x20
[ 6429.878046]  [<ffffffffc061ef49>] iwl_pcie_apm_stop+0x6b9/0x790 [iwlwifi]
[ 6429.878051]  [<ffffffffc061f459>] iwl_trans_pcie_stop_device+0x109/0x570 [iwlwifi]
[ 6429.878057]  [<ffffffffc0aa4c50>] iwl_mvm_up+0x340/0x440 [iwlmvm]
[ 6429.878060]  [<ffffffff81738798>] ? ip_mc_inc_group+0x68/0x2b0
[ 6429.878064]  [<ffffffff817b03f3>] ? rfkill_blocked+0x23/0x30
[ 6429.878069]  [<ffffffffc0aa94dc>] __iwl_mvm_mac_start+0x2c/0x370 [iwlmvm]
[ 6429.878074]  [<ffffffffc0aa9848>] iwl_mvm_mac_start+0x28/0x40 [iwlmvm]
[ 6429.878086]  [<ffffffffc07e3c84>] ieee80211_do_open+0x324/0xde0 [mac80211]
[ 6429.878096]  [<ffffffffc07e47b1>] ieee80211_open+0x71/0x80 [mac80211]
[ 6429.878099]  [<ffffffff816c12d6>] __dev_open+0xb6/0x130
[ 6429.878102]  [<ffffffff816c1601>] __dev_change_flags+0xa1/0x170
[ 6429.878104]  [<ffffffff816c16f9>] dev_change_flags+0x29/0x70
[ 6429.878107]  [<ffffffff816d0e67>] do_setlink+0x3a7/0xb80
[ 6429.878111]  [<ffffffff81198bf0>] ? zone_statistics+0x80/0xa0
[ 6429.878113]  [<ffffffff81198bf0>] ? zone_statistics+0x80/0xa0
[ 6429.878117]  [<ffffffff813df622>] ? nla_parse+0x32/0x120
[ 6429.878119]  [<ffffffff816d1d7d>] rtnl_newlink+0x5fd/0x7a0
[ 6429.878123]  [<ffffffff81312aa8>] ? security_capable+0x18/0x20
[ 6429.878126]  [<ffffffff8107e64d>] ? ns_capable+0x2d/0x60
[ 6429.878128]  [<ffffffff816cdee2>] rtnetlink_rcv_msg+0x92/0x260
[ 6429.878131]  [<ffffffff817c4f19>] ? schedule_preempt_disabled+0x29/0x70
[ 6429.878134]  [<ffffffff817c6e1d>] ? __mutex_lock_slowpath+0xdd/0x100
[ 6429.878136]  [<ffffffff816cde50>] ? rtnetlink_rcv+0x40/0x40
[ 6429.878139]  [<ffffffff816ef389>] netlink_rcv_skb+0xb9/0xe0
[ 6429.878142]  [<ffffffff816cde3c>] rtnetlink_rcv+0x2c/0x40
[ 6429.878144]  [<ffffffff816eeac1>] netlink_unicast+0x111/0x1b0
[ 6429.878147]  [<ffffffff816eee67>] netlink_sendmsg+0x307/0x650
[ 6429.878149]  [<ffffffff8135eb30>] ? aa_sk_perm.isra.4+0x70/0x170
[ 6429.878153]  [<ffffffff816a33dc>] do_sock_sendmsg+0x8c/0x100
[ 6429.878155]  [<ffffffff816a2d7c>] ? copy_msghdr_from_user+0x15c/0x210
[ 6429.878158]  [<ffffffff816a3a38>] ___sys_sendmsg+0x348/0x360
[ 6429.878161]  [<ffffffff811a5cd0>] ? tlb_flush_mmu_free+0x40/0x60
[ 6429.878163]  [<ffffffff811a68fc>] ? tlb_finish_mmu+0x1c/0x50
[ 6429.878165]  [<ffffffff81211d55>] ? __fget_light+0x25/0x70
[ 6429.878167]  [<ffffffff81211db3>] ? __fdget+0x13/0x20
[ 6429.878170]  [<ffffffff816a36a0>] ? SYSC_sendto+0x1c0/0x210
[ 6429.878173]  [<ffffffff816a4152>] __sys_sendmsg+0x42/0x80
[ 6429.878175]  [<ffffffff816a41a2>] SyS_sendmsg+0x12/0x20
[ 6429.878179]  [<ffffffff817c934d>] system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
[ 6429.878180] ---[ end trace 9ee1cb823174d4be ]---
[ 6429.878184] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Access time out - failed to enable LP XTAL
```